# Automapper doesn't work between class and struct AfterMap

Tags: c#, wcf, automapper

Suppose this Enum contract :

```
  [DataContract]
public enum ReportType_DTO
{
    [EnumMember]
    Voice,
    [EnumMember]
    Text,
    [EnumMember]
    File
}
```

which have three members from 0 to 2 in the other side I have another Enum which have 7 member as:

```
 public enum RptType
{
    Word = 0,
    Dynamic = 1,
    Basic = 2,
    StructuredReport = 3,
    Word2007 = 4,
    PDF = 5,
    WebReport = 6,
    WebTemplate = 7
}
```

so I configure mapping as:

```
  var mapper1 = new MapperConfiguration((cfg) =>
            cfg.CreateMap<Report_C, Report_DTO>().AfterMap((reportC, reportDTO) =>
            { 
                switch ((RptType)reportC.Type)
                {
                    case RptType.Dynamic:
                    case RptType.PDF:
                    case RptType.Word:
                    case RptType.Word2007:
                    case RptType.WebTemplate:
                        reportDTO.Type = ReportType_DTO.File;
                        break;
                    case RptType.StructuredReport:
                        reportDTO.Type = ReportType_DTO.Voice;
                        break;
                    case RptType.Basic:
                    case RptType.WebReport:
                        reportDTO.Type = ReportType_DTO.Text;
                        break;
                }
                reportDTO.ReportUID = reportC.SOPInstanceUID;
            }))
            .CreateMapper();
```

and map the collection one by one:

```
  var foundReports = pacsReports.Collection.Select(r => mapper1.Map<Report_DTO>(r)).ToList();
```

case `RptType.StructuredReport` happened for one of collections member but when I checked the collection it seem that prop doesn't get new value as picture below: 
[image]

this is clear in client-side we ending up with exception like :

> > Enum value '3' is invalid for type 'xxx.ReportType_DTO' and cannot be serialized. Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute attribute.

is there another ways to force Automapper change the value explicitly?

**UPDATE1:**

`Report_DTO` is a struct type but `Report_C` is a class, can it be the reason (something like call by reference  or call by value for `struct` in mapping)  ?

**UPDATE2:**

Yes `struct` is the reason, by changing struct to class it work well, but I am returning `DTO_OUT` as struct for some reason to force operation don't return null so I can't change them to class, I believe there must be a solution to tell autommaper call by reference, I think `AfterMape` is a void method which change entered param in call by reference mechanism.

any idea and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, `struct` definitely can be a reason - you are modifying a copy.

Comment: Let me change it to `class` will be back asap.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes that was the problem as we guessed, but I can't change the struct to class as I mentined in update 2, what is your opinion ?

Comment: Create map from `RptType` to `ReportType_DTO`? But looks like `reportC.Type` is `int`?

Comment: @IvanStoev, I think this is not the reason because by changing it to class it get worked well, Yes `reportC.Type` is int.

Comment: We are on the same page for the cause of the issue. My previous comment was a suggestion how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to let AutoMapper pass `struct` by reference to `AfterMap` action. So you need a different approach, not based on `AfterMap`.

One way is to create mapping from `RptType` to `ReportType_DTO` wrapping the switch logic in `ConvertUsing`. Then create a mapping from `Report_C` to `Report_DTO` with typical `ForMember` setup:

```
var mapper1 = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<RptType, ReportType_DTO>().ConvertUsing(rptType =>
    {
        switch (rptType)
        {
            case RptType.StructuredReport:
                return ReportType_DTO.Voice;
            case RptType.Basic:
            case RptType.WebReport:
                return ReportType_DTO.Text;
            default:
                return ReportType_DTO.File;
        }
    });

    cfg.CreateMap<Report_C, Report_DTO>()
        .ForMember(reportDTO => reportDTO.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(reportC => (RptType)reportC.Type))
        .ForMember(reportDTO => reportDTO.ReportUID, opt => opt.MapFrom(reportC => reportC.SOPInstanceUID));
})
.CreateMapper();
```

Comment: Up vote,Yes right, `ConvertUsing` can be the solution but there is still some problem that all the member should be mapped manually, in action Automapper nothing do automatically.

Comment: Well, it does "auto" for properties with the same name and type. You have to specify only the differences like above (first because pf the different type, other because of the different names).